# Generate entry widgets in tkinter gui using combobox, then get the values entered for use later in script

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python script that uses tkinter gui to generate entry boxes for user value insertion. The number of entry boxes generated is chosen from a combobox (either 1 or 2) which allow the user to enter data for the appropriate number of items. These values should then populate a dictionary so they can be called on later to be used as variables.  I am able to generate the boxes, but when I enter the data and submit, the values do not seem to be populating the dictionary.

I tried this:

```py
import os
import re
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Rack Position & Injection Volume')
root.geometry("700x200")

numbers = [1, 2]
combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=numbers)
combo.grid(row=0, column=1)
combo.set(numbers[0])
combo_label = tk.Label(root, text="Select number of plates for this sequence:").grid(column=0, row=0)
combo['state'] = 'normal'
global selected_number
slected_number= int(combo.get())


def generate_entry_boxes():
    global selected_number, entry1_boxes, entry2_boxes, entry1_labels, entry1_values, entry2_values, entry2_labels, buttons
    entry1_boxes = []
    entry1_values = {}
    entry2_boxes = []
    entry2_values = {}
    entry_labels = []
    entry2_labels = []
    buttons = []
    for entry in entry1_boxes:
        entry.destroy()
        entry1_boxes.clear()
    for entry2 in entry2_boxes:
        entry2.destroy()
        entry2_boxes.clear()
    for label in entry_labels:
        label.destroy()
        entry_labels.clear()
    for label2 in entry2_labels:
        label2.destroy()
        entry2_labels.clear()
    for button in buttons:
        button.destroy()
        buttons.clear()

    for i in range(slected_number):
        entry1_values[i] = tk.StringVar()
        entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry1_values[i])
        entry1.grid(row=i+1, column=1)
        entry1_boxes.append(entry1)
        entry2_values[i] = tk.StringVar()
        entry2 = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry2_values[i])
        entry2.grid(row=i+1, column=3)
        entry2_boxes.append(entry2)
        label = ttk.Label(root, text="Position of plate " + str(i+1) + ":")
        label.grid(row=i+1, column=0)
        entry_labels.append(label)
        label2 = ttk.Label(root, text="Injection Volume(uL):")
        label2.grid(row=i+1, column=2)
        entry2_labels.append(label2)
        button = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=get_entries)
        button.grid(row=selected_number + 1, column=1)
        buttons.append(button)


def get_entries():
    for i, entry in enumerate(entry1_boxes):
        entry1_values[i] = entry.get()
    for i, entry in enumerate(entry2_boxes):
        entry2_values[i] = entry.get()
    entry_plate1 = entry1_values.get('0', 'Key not found')
    entry_plate2 = entry1_values.get('1', 'Key not found')
    entry_vol1 = entry2_values.get('0', 'Key not found')
    entry_vol2 = entry2_values.get('1', 'Key not found')
    condition_mask = df['Vial Position'] == 1
    second_occurrence_index = df[condition_mask].index[1]
    after_mask = df.index >= second_occurrence_index
    df.loc[~after_mask, 'Rack Position'] = entry_plate1
    df.loc[after_mask, 'Rack Position'] = entry_plate2
    df['Plate Position'] = df['Rack Position']
    df.loc[~after_mask, 'Injection Volume'] = entry_vol1
    df.loc[after_mask, 'Injection Volume'] = entry_vol2


combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event: generate_entry_boxes())
root.mainloop()
```

and expected to get the values for `entry_plate1`, `entry_plate2`, `entry_vol1`, and `entry_vol2` from the generated entry boxes, but instead my data shows **Key not found**.

Comment: There is typo: `selected_number` or `slected_number`?  Also `df` is undefined.  If it is not necessary to reproduce the issue, remove code related to make it a [mre].  Post the full traceback as well.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this.  I'll adjust the code to make it reproducable

Comment: Running your code generates a "NameError: name 'selected_number' is not defined" error.
Try changing `global selected_number` to `selected_number = 1`

Comment: line 74, in get_entries
    condition_mask = df['Vial Position'] == 1
                     ^^
NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Comment: it is good practice to use `get()` and `set()` methods in place of `global` to access tkinter variables in functions...

Answer (score 0):

There are issues in your code:

- typo: `slected_number` should be `selected_number`
- need to create and initialize those lists and dictionaries outside `generate_entry_boxes()`
- need to clear those lists and dictionaries after the for loops
- need to create only one "Submit" button
- need to call `selected_number = int(combo.get())` inside `generate_entry_boxes()`
- need to use integer instead of string for the key when calling those `xxxxx_values.get(...)` inside `get_entries()`

Below is the required changes to fix the issues:

```py
...
# below lines are not necessary
#global selected_number
#slected_number= int(combo.get())

# initialize the lists and dictionaries
entry1_boxes = []
entry1_values = {}
entry2_boxes = []
entry2_values = {}
entry_labels = []
entry2_labels = []
buttons = []

def generate_entry_boxes():
    global selected_number, entry1_boxes, entry2_boxes, entry1_labels, entry1_values, entry2_values, entry2_labels, buttons
    for entry in entry1_boxes:
        entry.destroy()
    # clear list after the for loop
    entry1_boxes.clear()
    for entry2 in entry2_boxes:
        entry2.destroy()
    entry2_boxes.clear()
    for label in entry_labels:
        label.destroy()
    entry_labels.clear()
    for label2 in entry2_labels:
        label2.destroy()
    entry2_labels.clear()
    for button in buttons:
        button.destroy()
    buttons.clear()

    # get the selected number from the combobox
    selected_number = int(combo.get())
    # fix typo "slected_number" -> "selected_number"
    for i in range(selected_number):
        ...
    # need to create only one submit button after the for loop
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=get_entries)
    button.grid(row=selected_number + 1, column=1)
    buttons.append(button)

def get_entries():
    ...
    # use integers as keys
    entry_plate1 = entry1_values.get(0, 'Key not found')
    entry_plate2 = entry1_values.get(1, 'Key not found')
    entry_vol1 = entry2_values.get(0, 'Key not found')
    entry_vol2 = entry2_values.get(1, 'Key not found')
    ...
```